# Having trouble running executing command with ant build

Tags: java, cmd, ant

I have this set up in the ant build

```
<target name="wkHtmlToPDF" >
        <exec dir="output/exec/" executable="cmd">
            <arg value="ruby doc_to_pdf.rb /help/en/pages/intro.htm /help/intro.pdf"/>
        </exec>
    </target>
```

I have a ruby file that's taking in an html file and outputting a PDF file, I've tried this several different ways, with each space being separated by a new arg value and etc
and when I run the build on the command line, or in eclipse, this is the result. Its not actually running my command. However I've tried typing in the command I'm trying to run in the cmd itself, and it works perfectly, any help would be appreciated 

[image: output]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the `cmd`, the `exec` should be:

```
<exec dir="output/exec/" executable="cmd">
  <arg value="/C"/>
  <arg value="ruby doc_to_pdf.rb /help/en/pages/intro.htm /help/intro.pdf"/>
</exec>
```

However you probably don't need to go through `cmd`. If you can run `ruby` as an executable directly on the command line (i.e. the executable is listed in the `PATH` environment variable), then it should also be possible with the Ant `exec`. So try also:

```
<exec dir="output/exec/" executable="ruby">
  <arg line="doc_to_pdf.rb /help/en/pages/intro.htm /help/intro.pdf"/>
</exec>
```

Note that this uses `line` instead of `value` for the `arg`. The difference is documented in https://ant.apache.org/manual/using.html#arg.

Comment: Thank you so much, that second option about running the ruby executable worked perfectly!